# Kubernetes Pod Security checks for InitContainer

Tags: security, kubernetes, penetration-testing, checkov, kube-bench

Container must follow the Security best Practices from Kubernetes Community and developers and they need to apply alle the Recommendation from CIS Benchmark.

what about InitContainer ,should they also follow the same Practices?

and what if not , which Security Threads could come from Completed Container?

thanks

Comment: Did the provided answer help you, do you need more help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about InitContainer ,should they also follow the same Practices?

- Yes

what if not , which Security Threads could come from Completed Container?

- they could perform damage before getting into completed state.